# Categorizing a pair of variable based on unique occurence of either one

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I'm having some issues labelling pairs of variables. I essentially have to columns, one of them is a set of charcaters, and the other one numerical values. I would like that if one or the other is used, it constitutes a category or id. Suppose that an observation has 'a' as a char variable, and 1 as a numerical variable, it gets categorised as 'id_1' (or any other unique identifier). Then if either 'a' or 1 is used again in combination with any other variable (e.g. 'a' with any numerical value, or 1 with any character value), it also gets categorised as 'id_1'. (e.g. the same unique identifier)

Here's an example of my problem, and the way I would like for the pairs to be categorized. However, the actual system of categorization doesn't matter as long as they are uniquely identifiable.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df = tibble(
  var_1 = c('a','b','b','a','c','d','c','d','e','f','f','e','a'),
  var_2 = c(1,2,1,2,3,4,4,3,5,6,7,5,8),
  cat = c('id_1','id_1','id_1','id_1','id_3','id_3','id_3','id_3','id_5','id_6','id_6','id_5','id_1')
)

# A tibble: 12 × 3
   var_1 var_2 cat  
   <chr> <dbl> <chr>
 1 a         1 id_1 
 2 b         2 id_1 
 3 b         1 id_1 
 4 a         2 id_1 
 5 c         3 id_3 
 6 d         4 id_3 
 7 c         4 id_3 
 8 d         3 id_3 
 9 e         5 id_5 
10 f         6 id_6 
11 f         7 id_6 
12 e         5 id_5
13 a         8 id_1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to match your requirements. Row 1 correctly gets assigned `id_1`, but row 2 should be `id_2` as far as I can see: neither `b` nor `2` has been used before.

Comment: You're correct, in row 2, b or 2 have not been assigned yet. But later on, b is associated with 1, and a with 2.  To me this is supposed to represent one unique category for the set of underlying values and observations.
I'm not sure why order matters, if I randomize the dataset above and you categorize it by hand you should still arrive at the same result, since I'm looking at the aggregate rather than row by row.

Comment: Essentially, I'm trying to take a pair of values, from var_1 and var_2, and check if either observations is present elsewhere. If that's the case, then I'd like those other observations to be categorized with the same identifier, even if their corresponding var_1 and var_2 don't match. I don't even know if it's possible without absurd code or computational requirements, because each pair of var_1 and var_2 would have to be checked against the rest of the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a basic clustering-algorithm from network analysis to see which values occur together to get the specified ids. I get the same groups as you specified only slightly different names, because you didn't use some ids like `id_2`.

```r
df <-  data.frame(
  var_1 = c('a','b','b','a','c','d','c','d','e','f','f','e','a'),
  var_2 = c(1,2,1,2,3,4,4,3,5,6,7,5,8),
  cat = c('id_1','id_1','id_1','id_1','id_3','id_3','id_3','id_3','id_5','id_6','id_6','id_5','id_1')
)

library(igraph)
cluster.results <- clusters(graph.data.frame(df)) # only the first two columns are used to create the graph for clustering

df.cluster <- data.frame(
  var_1= names(cluster.results$membership), 
  cat2 = paste0("id_", cluster.results$membership)
)

df <- merge(df, df.cluster, by = "var_1")
df
#>    var_1 var_2  cat cat2
#> 1      a     1 id_1 id_1
#> 2      a     2 id_1 id_1
#> 3      a     8 id_1 id_1
#> 4      b     2 id_1 id_1
#> 5      b     1 id_1 id_1
#> 6      c     4 id_3 id_2
#> 7      c     3 id_3 id_2
#> 8      d     4 id_3 id_2
#> 9      d     3 id_3 id_2
#> 10     e     5 id_5 id_3
#> 11     e     5 id_5 id_3
#> 12     f     6 id_6 id_4
#> 13     f     7 id_6 id_4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! This seems to do exactly what I want!